# Local Variable 'user_form' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, json, django

I am running a website using Django .

Here is the code (views.py):

```
def signup(request):
registered=False
failed_ref=False
wrong_ref=False
    if request.method=='POST':
        if 'city' in request.POST:
            user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
            profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST)
            if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
               user = user_form.save()
               user.set_password(user.password)
               user.save()
               profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
               profile.user = user
               try:
                   ref_con = profile.referral_contact
                   if ref_con == profile.mobile_no:
                   failed_ref=True
                   elif ref_con == Profile.objects.get(mobile_no=ref_con).mobile_no:
                       prof = Profile.objects.get(mobile_no=ref_con)
                       wallet_rec = Wallet.objects.get(profile=prof)
                       wall = Wallet.objects.get(profile=profile)
                       registered = True

                except Profile.DoesNotExist:
                    wrong_ref = True
                data={'registered':registered,'failed_ref':failed_ref,'wrong_ref':wrong_ref}
                return JsonResponse(data,safe=False)
    else:
        user_form=UserForm()
        profile_form=ProfileForm()
    return JsonResponse({'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered,
                                                    'failed_ref':failed_ref,'wrong_ref':wrong_ref})
```

For this, i need to get response in JSON . When i run , i am getting error "local variable 'user_form' referenced before assignment".What change i need to do ?. I am bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

This condition must be failing

```
if 'city' in request.POST:
```

hence

```
user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST) # is an unreachable code
```

hence `user_form` remains undefined.

Resulting in error `"local variable 'user_form' referenced before assignment"`

Possible solution:

```
def signup(request):
    registered=False
    failed_ref=False
    wrong_ref=False
    if request.method=='POST':
        # Defined the variables before the condition 
        #
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST)
        if 'city' in request.POST:
            if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                user = user_form.save()
                user.set_password(user.password)
                user.save()
                profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = user
                try:
                    ref_con = profile.referral_contact
                    if ref_con == profile.mobile_no:
                        failed_ref=True
                    elif ref_con == Profile.objects.get(mobile_no=ref_con).mobile_no:
                        prof = Profile.objects.get(mobile_no=ref_con)
                        wallet_rec = Wallet.objects.get(profile=prof)
                        wall = Wallet.objects.get(profile=profile)
                        registered = True

                except Profile.DoesNotExist:
                    wrong_ref = True
                    data={'registered':registered,'failed_ref':failed_ref,'wrong_ref':wrong_ref}
                    return JsonResponse(data,safe=False)
    else:
        user_form=UserForm()
        profile_form=ProfileForm()
        return JsonResponse({'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered,
            'failed_ref':failed_ref,'wrong_ref':wrong_ref})
```

Comment: Yeah got it fixed . Thanks